# Abstracting away android and ios using web app

Tags: android, ios, html, web-applications

I want to develop an application and am debating between android and ios.

Recently i had an idea, what if i made the whole app a web app, and used ios and android as containers for said web app.

Basically i want to know what constraints do i have that will force me to use android / ios specefic code. I.e. what can't i do in the web app, bearing in mind it will use html5 and have local storage options, it seems to me that their is almost no difference between a web app and a native app.

Comment: PERFORMANCE! At least on iOS it is far more performant to use native code rather than some html5 with javascript etc.

Comment: The performance depends on the action you are doing and the JavaScript interpreter used in the browser. In some cases (like simple mathematic calculations) the JavaScript interpreter of Chrome is more performant that a native Android app.

Answer (score 0):

As web app you can't access OS specific actions like e.g. Notifications or running actions in the background (while your app is closed) triggered by the OS.

But if you wan't to develop an HypridApp (a web app in an OS specific container) you can have a look at [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/).